# rename files in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I rename each file in folder:

pattern is:    (first part of file name).digit_(endoffilename)

for example

```
a.1_f
b.2_f
c.3_g
```

I would like to replace it with

```
a.01_f
b.02_f
c.03_ g
```

...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_ -replace '([^.]+)\.(\d)(\w)', '$1.0$2$3'} -wh
```

Or if you have more than nine files:

```
gci | ? {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match '([^.]+\.)(\d)(\w+)'} |  
  rni -NewName {$matches[1] + ("{0:00}" -f [int]$matches[2]) + $matches[3]} -wh
```

The second example uses aliases to shorten the command (easier for typing).  `gci` is the alias for `Get-ChildItem`, `?` is the alias for `Where-Object` and `rni` is the alias for `Rename-Item`.  The `-wh` invokes the `WhatIf` functionality where PowerShell will show you what it would do so you can twiddle with the command until you're happy with what the results would be.  Then remove the `-wh` to actually execute it.

Comment: is $1 first pair of brackets $2 the second one and so on ?

Comment: $1, $2, etc is how your reference the regex capture group.  The first approach really only works if you files go 01..09 and breaks down for 10.  The second approach is a bit gnarlier but works in general - 00..99.  You can even increase the number of zeros in "{0:000}" to get 000..999.

Comment: Could You please comment this line matches[1] + ("{0:00}" -f [int]$matches[2]) + $matches[3]

Comment: $matches variable contains an array of capture groups that the operator `-match` creates.  $matches[1] corresponds to this part of the regex ([^.]+\.) which captures `a.` part of the filename.  $matches[2] is the digit and $matches[3] is the rest of the filename.  "{0:00}" -f [int]$matches[2] is a string formatting operation that takes say 1, converts it from string to int and then displays it as 01.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to break the file apart via regular expressions, then assemble the new file name from the parts, followed by a `Rename-Item`

- A regex matching your files might be `\w+\.\d+_\w`
- To print "001" when you have 1, you could use the format operator, such as "{0:000}" -f 1
- To loop through the files, use `Get-ChildItem` & `Foreach-Object`, or as I like to write `ls | % {}`

Comment: How do you break a file name apart and then reassemble when using ls | %{ }?